# How can I iterate token attributes with coreference results in CoreNLP?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I am looking for a way to extract and merge annotation results from CoreNLP. To specify,

```
import stanza
import os
from stanza.server import CoreNLPClient
corenlp_dir = '/Users/fatih/stanford-corenlp-4.2.0/'
os.environ['CORENLP_HOME'] = corenlp_dir

client = CoreNLPClient(
    annotators=['tokenize','ssplit', 'pos', 'lemma', 'ner', 'coref'], 
    memory='4G', 
    endpoint='http://localhost:9001',
    be_quiet=True)

text = "Barack Obama was born in Hawaii.  He is the president. Obama was elected in 2008."

doc = client.annotate(text)

for x in doc.corefChain:
    for y in x.mention:
        print(y.animacy)
        
ANIMATE
ANIMATE
ANIMATE
```

I'd like to merge these results with the ones from following code:

```
for i, sent in enumerate(document.sentence):
    print("[Sentence {}]".format(i+1))
    for t in sent.token:
        print("{:12s}\t{:12s}\t{:6s}\t{}".format(t.word, t.lemma, t.pos, t.ner))
    print("")

Barack          Barack          NNP     PERSON
Obama           Obama           NNP     PERSON
was             be              VBD     O
born            bear            VBN     O
in              in              IN      O
Hawaii          Hawaii          NNP     STATE_OR_PROVINCE
.               .               .       O

[Sentence 2]
He              he              PRP     O
is              be              VBZ     O
the             the             DT      O
president       president       NN      TITLE
.               .               .       O

[Sentence 3]
Obama           Obama           NNP     PERSON
was             be              VBD     O
elected         elect           VBN     O
in              in              IN      O
2008            2008            CD      DATE
.               .               .       O
```

Since annotations are stored in different object, I cannot iterate over the two different object and get the results for related items.

Is there a way out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coref chains have a sentenceIndex and a beginIndex which should correlate to the position in the sentence.  You can use this to correlate the two.

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/stanza/blob/f0338f891a03e242c7e11e440dec6e191d54ab77/doc/CoreNLP.proto#L319

Edit: quick and dirty change to your example code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from stanza.server import CoreNLPClient

client = CoreNLPClient(
    annotators=['tokenize','ssplit', 'pos', 'lemma', 'ner', 'coref'],
    be_quiet=False)

text = "Barack Obama was born in Hawaii.  In 2008 he became the president."

doc = client.annotate(text)

animacy = defaultdict(dict)
for x in doc.corefChain:
    for y in x.mention:
        print(y.animacy)
        for i in range(y.beginIndex, y.endIndex):
            animacy[y.sentenceIndex][i] = True
            print(y.sentenceIndex, i)

for sent_idx, sent in enumerate(doc.sentence):
    print("[Sentence {}]".format(sent_idx+1))
    for t_idx, token in enumerate(sent.token):
        animate = animacy[sent_idx].get(t_idx, False)
        print("{:12s}\t{:12s}\t{:6s}\t{:20s}\t{}".format(token.word, token.lemma, token.pos, token.ner, animate))
    print("")
```